# Juego de Preguntas Android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Quería solicitar de su ayuda soy nuevo programando en android
y quería ver si me ayudaban a resolver un problema que tengo.

Lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente tengo un textview donde quiero generar 3 preguntas(1 a la vez) y tengo 3 radiobutton que serian las posibles respuestas a cada pregunta y tengo un botón. al iniciar la aplicación estaría mostrando la primera pregunta y 3 posibles respuestas, cuando el usuario presione el botón tendría que aparecer la segunda pregunta(siempre en la misma vista no debo crear otra vista) y así sucesivamente(son 4 preguntas las que tengo que hacer) al finalizar las 4 preguntas tengo que mostrar cuantos preguntas se contestaron bien y cuantas mal(esto lo mostraria al final en otros textview.

Se que tendria que ir evaluando pero no logro hacerlo, esto es lo que tengo

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView pregunta, finalbuenas;
RadioButton res1, res2, res3;
Button siguiente;
int buenas = 0;
int malas = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    pregunta = findViewById(R.id.tvPregunta);
    finalbuenas = findViewById(R.id.tvbuenas);
    res1 = findViewById(R.id.rdbRespuesta1);
    res2 = findViewById(R.id.rdbRespuesta2);
    res3 = findViewById(R.id.rdbRespuesta3);
    siguiente = findViewById(R.id.btnSiguiente);

    pregunta.setText("Que año es");
    res1.setText("2019");
    res2.setText("2018");
    res3.setText("2017");


}

public void Siguiente(View v) {
    //para la primera pregunta la respuesta seria la primera
    if (res1.isChecked()) {
        buenas += 1; //este es el contador que utilizaría para saber cuantas buenas fueron
        //formulo pregunta 2
        pregunta.setText("Que dia es hoy");
        res1.setText("Lunes");
        res2.setText("Martes");
        res3.setText("Miercoles");

    }

}
```

}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Se me olvidó mencionar que lo tengo que resolver solo con estructuras repetitivas. Algo así como lo que puse en el código

Comment: Saludos @CristianTorres, lo que necesitas para eso o al menos te puede servir para eso es en esa `activity` implementar `fragments`, de forma que al seleccionar la respuesta, cambie de ese `fragment` a otro, guardando la respuesta que coloco, en un `SharedPreferences` por ejemplo, luego que guardes todos los datos que necesitas los recuperas en el ultimo `fragment`, que seria el de resultados, validas que lo que ingresó sea correcto y de acuerdo a eso colocas el resultado, es una idea. Revisa también el uso de [intents](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent)

Comment: [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments?hl=es-419) [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences). Acá las respectivas documentaciones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta respuesta utiliza vectores, podés implementar lo mismo usando listas.

1) Claramente tenés una estructura bien definida donde una pregunta consta de la pregunta en sí, 3 posibles resultados, y 1 de ellos el correcto. Esto lo podés modelar en una clase:

```
public class Pregunta{
 private String texto;
 private String [] respuestas = new String[3];
 private int respuesta correcta;

 // Constructor para facilitar crear las preguntas
 public Pregunta(String texto, String r1, String r2, String r3, int rcorrecta){
     this.texto = texto;
     this.respuestas[0] = r1;
     this.respuestas[1] = r2;
     this.respuestas[2] = r3;
     this.correcta = rcorrecta;
 )
 // Falta agregar los Getters & Setters
}
```

2) Necesitas 4 preguntas entonces en `onCreate()` podés crearlas y guardarlas en un vector o en una lista.

```
// preguntas debe ser un atributo de la clase para poder accederlo desde diferentes métodos.
private Pregunta [] preguntas = new Pregunta[4];

// en onCreate()
preguntas[0] = new Pregunta("¿Qué año es?", "2019","2018","2017",1);
preguntas[1] = new Pregunta(...);
preguntas[2] = new Pregunta(...);
preguntas[3] = new Pregunta(...);
```

3) Ahora necestas un atributo para saber en que pregunta estas (arranca con la primera que es la cero en el array de preguntas).

```
private int preguntaActual = 0;
```

4) Vamos a hacer un metodo que actualice la pregunta en pantalla similar a lo que hiciste en `onCreate()` (y luego llamar ese metodo al final de `onCreate()` en lugar del código actual, y también al pasar a la nueva pregunta).

```
public void mostrarPreguntaActual(){
    Pregunta infoDePregunta = preguntas[preguntaActual];
    pregunta.setText(infoDePregunta.getTexto());
    res1.setText(infoDePregunta.getRespuestas()[0]);
    res2.setText(infoDePregunta.getRespuestas()[1]);
    res3.setText(infoDePregunta.getRespuestas()[2]);
}
```

5) A `siguiente` le falta el onClickListener. Al hacer click neceistamos validar la pregunta actual, guardar si es buena o mala,  y mostrar la siguiente:

```
siguiente.setOnclickListener((view) -> {
    validarYPasarAPreguntaSiguiente();
});
```

6) Validar la pregunta actual y pasar a la siguiente generalizando lo que tenías hecho:

```
public validarYPasarAPreguntaSiguiente(){
    // Obtiene selección del usuario
    int resultadoSeleccionado = -1;
    if(res1.isChecked()){
         resultadoSeleccionado = 0;
    }else if(res2.isChecked()){
         resultadoSeleccionado = 1;
    }else if(res2.isChecked()){
         resultadoSeleccionado = 2;
    }

    // guarda si es correcta o no
    if(preguntas[preguntaActual].getRespuestaCorrecta() == resultadoSeleccionado){
        buenas++;
    }else{
        malas++;
    }

    // Pasa a la siguiente pregunta o si es la última muestra el resultado final.
    preguntaActual++;
    if(preguntaActual < 5){
        mostrarPreguntaActual();
    }else{
        siguiente.setEnabled(false); // No mas clicks en siguiente si llegamos al final
        mostrarResultado();
    }
}
```

7) Armar el texto del resultado y mostrarlo en pantalla

```
public void mostrarResultado(){
    // Para mostrar el resultado tenes que armar el texto con los datos de buenos
    // y setear el texto en finalbuenas 
    // Este TextView inicialmente tendrá visibility gone y para mostrarlo 
    // hay que pasarlo a visible (en este método).
}
```